# How can i connect my headphones with Jack running through Ubuntu Studio Controls?

Tags: headphones, ubuntu-studio, jack

I cannot connect my headphones while running Jack through Studio Controls.

I can find them when Jack is stopped but not with it running.[image]

Comment: You need to use Alsa to manage that, Ubuntustudio comes with Qasmixer, that's the application you should use to control your output devices when you run jack.